# Redirect a button from a mobile browser to a messaging app on phone

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, mobile

Viewing on mobile browser: I have a contact page and i want to add a "SMS" button that when a user clicked it, it will redirect to the default messaging app on mobile together with a set contact number.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Try this link. http://danielmuller.asia/2013/02/android-open-an-app-from-web-link-or-fallback-to-market/

Answer (score 0):

A biref summary of the functioning of the code I have provided.
On the click of "SMS" button a javascript function will be called which would takeup the value of the **contact_no** field and redirect to page URL of your default messaging app.

You need to include jquery file on your page:
Here I am providing a baisc code of how the thing works:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="contact_no_input_field" id="contact_no_input_field">
<input type="button" value="SMS" onclick="call_fun()">
<script type="text/javascript">
```

JS:

```
function call_fun()
{
     var contact_no = $('#contact_no_input_field').val();
     window.location.href="path/to/default messaging app/?contact_no="+contact_no;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this @rahul, i will try to find the messagin app path.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the path of the messaging app, I tried this: window.location.href="Messaging://?contact_no="+contact_no; but nothing works. Sorry I'm a newbie in mobile.

Comment: It should be the URL to page of your messaging APP page

Comment: I want to open the default sms app of the phone, I'm a bit confuse @Rahul